# How to cancel a broken StatefulSets rolling update?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, patroni

I have a PostgreSQL Kubernetes Service based on [Patroni](https://github.com/zalando/patroni)/[Spilo](https://github.com/zalando/spilo).
This Kubernetes service deploys a cluster of three PostgreSQL pods + three Etcd pods.
During maintenance, I had a failure and I wasn't able to restore the old configuration that worked fine before the rolling update.

I searched for documentation and it seems StatefulSets doesn't support rollbacks as deployment. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62425011/statefulset-unable-to-rollback-if-the-pods-are-not-in-running-state) that [references this doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#forced-rollback).

To be honest, however, I didn't understand how to proceed.

My cluster has the following pods:

```
postgres-0
postgres-1
postgres-2
etcd-0
etcd-1
etcd-2
```

my rolling update simply needed to upgrade the etcd image from 3.3.20 to 3.5.1. The upgrade started to update etcd-2 and the pod crashed for several reasons. So my intention was to stop the update and revert the etcd-2 to 3.3.20.

How I should proceed in a situation like this? How liveness and probing can help me here?
At the moment, the solution proposed in that thread is a bit confusing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To undo changes that have been made, first checkout the rollout history `kubectl rollout history sts <name> -n <namespace if not default>`.

Get more details about a revision `kubectl rollout history sts <name> --revision <number> -n <namespace if not default>`.

Undo the changes `kubectl rollout undo sts <name> --to-revision <number> -n <namespace if not default>`

Comment: I read this in other docs, but if I give the commands above I simply got ```Error from server (NotFound): statefulsets.apps "ccdb-cfdb" not found```, but the stateful sets exists.

Comment: These are my sts
```statefulset.apps/ccdb-cfdb statefulset.apps/ccdb-etcd```

Comment: Is there any setting on the server/YAML to enable the revision history tracking?

Comment: Have you specify the correct namespace? Updated answer just in case.

Comment: yes, you're right. The problem was the namespace. A really silly problem. Thank you.

Comment: When I list the revision of sts, do you know if it is possible to add a comment next to each revision so I can understand its content?

Comment: what revision does this command apply? Suppose I have already 5 revisions and I want to comment all of them, how I can do it by specifying the revision?

Comment: For StatefulSet, change cause is automatically maintain for you when you use `--record` with kubectl to manipulate your StatefulSet. Every successful changed will also automatically update `metadata.generation` which is the revision number. There's no official way to update these 2 fields by hand. Best bet is to use `kubectl rollout history sts <name> --revision <number>` to check what fields have changed.